# Database connections analysis in code - MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection

I'm analyzing a few VB.NET applications which connect to a MySQL database, but since I'm not the person who programmed them, there are a few doubts in this analysis in terms of when a DB connection is opened or closed.

By looking at the administration panel for MySQL it appears that not all opened connections are closed so I'd like to know if there is any tool that is capable of analyzing the source-code and detect when a connection is opened and if/when it's closed.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Why dont you just look for the open and closed methods? Find the connections name, trace that a .Close() exists in the scope used by the connection.

Comment: That is indeed an option (already considered), but having several classes which have over 10k lines of code renders that possibility difficult since the timeframe for analysis is short, which is why I placed the question.